# Subscription Form rendering doesn't exists in Layouts/Sublayouts

Tags: exm

Planning to implement Email Subscription functionality on our Sitecore Site.

I don't find the Subscription Form rendering in the Layouts/Sublayouts to add the form on the page as per this url,
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/35/email-experience-manager/en/the-subscription-form-control.html

We already using Sitecore Forms for Contact Us forms and EXM email messages for sending emails from contact us forms.

Do we need to install/enable any specific things to get this or anything to do at core?

Using Sitecore 9.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `Subscription Form` was removed from EXM in Sitecore 9, because the default behavior was incomplete and wasn't suitable for all the required scenarios.

Subscription management in EXM is provided as more of a full featured API with the expectation that it would be implemented to the client’s desires, you can take a look at the documentation for client API https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/the-email-experience-manager-client-api.html.

Depending on your requirements another option would be to use Marketing Automation to Subscribing the user, you can see some examples posted https://sitecorehacker.com/2018/12/22/marketing-automation-with-exm/